# How to decrease compile time when reading includes over a network?

Tags: speed

My project is very small but several includes are hosted on a network. Is there a way to speed up compile time and reduce latency without mirroring a local unsynced copy?

I've already mapped the source to a local folder on my system (Windows) and set the files to be "available offline" which syncs it locally. But when I go to compile I can see my network speed jump as it's (appears to be) reading from the network. After it's done compiling my network speed drops to zero.

If I've set these files and directories to be available offline then why isn't it using the local cache? Or does it only query the cache when offline? Can it be forced to read the cache?

My development environment is Windows 10 x64 and the files are hosted on a local server running CentOS 7 with samba. I am compiling from the command line using Make.

Comment: When it syncs it absolutely has to communicate over the network or it can't prove you are still in sync.  Are you sure your network utilization is identical regardless of sync?  That should be different.  But it would only be appreciable if the file size is significantly larger than the network overhead.

Comment: Why do you have include files hosted on a network? The normal way for distributing source files is version control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the "available offline" feature means that the latest retrieved copy will be cached for local use when the network share is no longer accessible.

However, as long as the network share is accessible, then the network copy will be used. Otherwise there'd be no way to actually maintain the synchronisation for later local use. There's no background process continually checking for remote file modification and syncing — it's a "sync as you use" mechanism.

You could set up a scheduled task to copy the remote files to some local folder every once in a while. You'd run the risk of compiling with out-of-date headers from time to time, but that seems to actually be what you're looking for.